# connection(); ^ TypeError: connection is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

connecting the mongodb i found an error
index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express=require('express')
const app= express;
const cors =require("cors");
//const port = 5000;
const connection = require("./db");

//db connection
connection();

//middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Listening on port${port}...`));
```

i tried to add the connecting lines but cannot resolve the error and get error again ( throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './db'
Require stack:)

Answer (score 0):

you does not share Fypdb file if you share it than I can tell what is problem in database file

in addition you missed call of express function

```js
const app = express()
```

Comment: in addition you missed call of express function

Comment: cannot resolve the problem can you please gave me your social or any account i can contact with you

Comment: its a db but i cannot understand what mean by it i just picked it on youtube to make a login and registration page

Comment: you can mail me on mohit.baraiya.personal@gmail.com or you can dm me on instagram with username mohit_baraiya666

Comment: are you working with mongodb?